# printing str values from list loop that resets if duplicates found in the result

Tags: python

I really can't figure out what's wrong with this loop, I tried editing it several times, but sometimes it prints duplicates ignoring the condition. after I edited it, it stopped printing anything at all... can somebody whos more experienced find out whats wrong here...

first attempt: it prints results with duplicates

```
from ast import Break
import random
import secrets

def checkIfDuplicates_2(x):
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     for elem in x:
        if elem in x:
            x = []
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
        elif elem not in x:
            print (x[0])
            print (x[1])
            print (x[2])
            print (x[3])
            print (x[4])
            break

questions = ["- Current Ratio:", "- Quick Ratio(ACID):", "- Inventory Turnover:", "- Average Age of Inventory:", "- Average Collection Period(ACP):", "- Average Payment Period(APP):", "- Total Assets Turnover:", "- Debit Ratio:", "- Times-Interest Earned Ratio(TIE):", "- Fixed-Payment Coverage Ratio(FPCR):", "- Gross Profit Margin(GPM):", "- Operating Profits Margin(OPM):", "- Net Profit Margin(NPM):", "- Earnings Per Share(EPS):", "- Return on Total Assets(ROA):", "- Return on Common Equity(ROE):", "- Price/Earnings Ratio(P/E):", "- Market/Book Ratio(M/B):"]
pool = []

# space between prints
spaces = " "
print(spaces * 5)
print("Find the following ratios:")
checkIfDuplicates_2(pool)
```

second attempt: I thought the problem with the 2nd (if) it has "x = []" so it clears the list so the loop can have a fresh start, so I replaced it with x.clear(). now it doesn't print anything at all

```
from ast import Break
import random
import secrets

def checkIfDuplicates_2(x):
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     x.append(random.choice(questions))
     for elem in x:
        if elem in x:
            x.clear()
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
            x.append(random.choice(questions))
        elif elem not in x:
            print (x[0])
            print (x[1])
            print (x[2])
            print (x[3])
            print (x[4])
            break

questions = ["- Current Ratio:", "- Quick Ratio(ACID):", "- Inventory Turnover:", "- Average Age of Inventory:", "- Average Collection Period(ACP):", "- Average Payment Period(APP):", "- Total Assets Turnover:", "- Debit Ratio:", "- Times-Interest Earned Ratio(TIE):", "- Fixed-Payment Coverage Ratio(FPCR):", "- Gross Profit Margin(GPM):", "- Operating Profits Margin(OPM):", "- Net Profit Margin(NPM):", "- Earnings Per Share(EPS):", "- Return on Total Assets(ROA):", "- Return on Common Equity(ROE):", "- Price/Earnings Ratio(P/E):", "- Market/Book Ratio(M/B):"]
pool = []

# space between prints
spaces = " "
print(spaces * 5)
print("Find the following ratios:")
checkIfDuplicates_2(pool)
```

Comment: There is no way to "reset" a loop in python, however, you con put your loop in a while loop, then break your inner loop to restart it. Break the while loop when you don't want it to restart anymore.

Comment: @RiccardoPiana I mean by resetting is resetting the (x) values so the duplicated values get omitted and the loop starts again on empty x so it doesn't append over the 1st 5 items in the list

Comment: Side note: when you repeat the same task over and over, you should consider using a loop. Also, if you have the same lines of code in several places in your code, consider using a function. If you don't know what a function is, then you should learn about them as soon as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the closely related random.sample() method? Takes a list and randomly samples the second argument's number of elements from the list.

```py
total_questions = 5
pool = random.sample(questions, total_questions)
print(pool)
```

Comment: omg, I already used this function already in previous code blocks, I have no idea how I forgot about it ... thanks a lot it solved my issue, I guess I just created a function and got my vision tunneled into making this function work...

Comment: No problem. If you want to figure out your function vs a different built in function I would actually do a while True loop that on every iteration removes a random element (selected from range(1, len(pool) + 1) from a copy of the questions list until len() of the copy is equal to total_questions. I agree, though, let's use built in functions when possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the condition is satisfied before print it. If not, try again.

```py
def checkIfDuplicates_2(x):
    total_questions = 5

    while True:
        for i in range(total_questions):
            x.append(random.choice(questions))

        if len(set(x)) == len(x):
            for i in range(len(x)):
                print(x[i])

            break
        else: 
            x = []
```

Comment: I took the opportunity to write a more generic code too.